How to draw on old 3d json object, then take the 2d svg's of these drawings?
I have created a kit designer which is a 3d json with this metadata:
"metadata":{
    "faces":5104,
    "vertices":5198,
    "uvs":1,
    "version":3,
    "normals":5198,
    "type":"Geometry",
    "generator":"io_three"
},

I am wrapping svg's around it - the code for this works perfectly and requires inputted code like this:
<div class="texture">
  <svg id ='horizontal-stripes' class="horizontal-stripes" width="1024" height="1024" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="primaryOnSvg" class="primary" width="1000" height="1000" fill="white"/>
    <!-- Horizontal stripes pattern -->
    <rect class="primary" x="0" y="100" width="1000" height="100" fill="white"/>
    <rect class="secondary" x="0" y="300" width="1000" height="100" fill="white"/>
    <rect class="tertiary" x="0" y="500" width="1000" height="100" fill="white"/>
    <rect class="accent" x="0" y="700" width="1000" height="100" fill="white"/>
    <rect class="primary" x="0" y="900" width="1000" height="100" fill="white"/>
  </svg>
</div>

where class defines the colour. All of this works perfectly, however at the moment rectangles/other shapes are essentially being drawn at random positions on the shirt and become curved and distorted due to the 3d objects shape. Are there any ways to quickly create other designs which can be made to actually resemble football kits, not just messy lines? Then, once these svg designs are made, can they be positioned like the above to fit within the rest of my work?
Any help would be much appreciated. 
